# Conver array of Json data to List<string> C#

Tags: c#, json

.NET 4.6.1 C#

I have a JSON object with a list of values in it:

[image]

I want to convert this to a List. I've tried this:

```
 //responseString contains the JSON
 string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectProfile>(responseString);
```

Here is ObjectProfile:

```
 internal class ObjectProfile
{
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

But the code throws an exception saying :

```
Message = "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'value', line 1, position 136."
```

How do I achieve my desired results? thanks

Comment: show the value of `responseString`

Comment: I did in the picture

Comment: i think your json is something like { "odata.metadata": "...", value: [{ "url": "..." }, { "url": "..." }]}, the values aren't strings. you can't get a list of strings in the way you are trying. Also, if you showed the value of the string i wouldn't have asked for it.  you have a screenshot of some devtools.

Comment: Judging by the image you provided, it seems like your `ObjectProfile` type doesn't match the actual shape of your JSON. The `value` porperty is an array of objects, each with a `url` property. What you need is `public List<SomeType> Value { get; set; }` when `SomeType` is `public class SomeType { public string Url { get; set; } }`

Comment: I know I can convert this to something. This data is trapped for life inside of this json string. I'll keep looking

Comment: @haim770 - Perfect! This is exactly what i needed. Thank you

Comment: Just FYI for future reference. Useful tool that I use when trying to create C# objects from JSON strings: http://json2csharp.com/ Obviously you can remove unnecessary properties as desired. Quite useful

Comment: @GeoffJames - thanks for this tool. I'll add it to  my collection